# Create custom variable names

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I have an orientational question that i'm not quite sure how to approach, so this is a request for advice.

For a project i'm working on i would like to assemble 'custom' variable names. For example, lets say i have this html page:

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="variable"></div>
    <div id="name"></div>
    <div id="custom"></div>
</div>
```

Now i know i can get the id's in jQuery with `$('div').attr('id')`. This is where my problem comes in:

I would like to create something like this line:

```
var variable_name_custom = 'Hello world';
```

where the var-name is generated by getting the div id's. (string div 1 + string div 2 + string div 3).

If i were to put the 3 names together right now, i would get the string 'variable_name_custom', but it would be a string-value of a variable, rather than the name of one.

Is this possible?

Comment: sorry, it's unclear what are you asking...

Comment: I don't understand the question

Comment: I tried to be as clear as possible. I want to construct the NAME of a variable through getting names of a page, rather than the VALUE of one. Does that help?

Comment: @Mortaza - you shouldn't create variable names dynamically, use an object and then create dynamic keys instead.

Comment: You might be better storing the data using `$('#name').data(key, value)` - https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

Comment: I know it's a bit of an odd question, but the project is rather large, so explaining the context would cause more questions than clarity :). I need to iterate through a lot of objects, generating variables that are named after themselves, and give them different values regarding position and color and such. So the variables need to be assembled with the items' own name. If that gives any clarity whatsoever :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no idea why you would want to do something like this but:

```
var varName = getName(); // will get you 'div1_div2_div3'.
window[varName] = 'Hello world';
alert(div1_div2_div3); // Hello World.
```

Now you can access the div1_div2_div3 global var you created.

Take a look at this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EK9Wj/)

Comment: Tried it, and this will do for me :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/wd99s/

```
window[$('div').attr('id')+'_'+$('span').attr('id')+'_'+$('p').attr('id')] = 'Sample';
console.log(window[$('div').attr('id')+'_'+$('span').attr('id')+'_'+$('p').attr('id')]);

<div id="variable"></div>
<span id="name"></span>
<p id="custom"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet is to change the var into a property of an object.

```
names = {};
names[id1+'_'+id2+'_'+id3] = 'Hello world';
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can use map function of Jquery

HTML Code

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="variable"></div>
    <div id="name"></div>
    <div id="custom"></div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var varname = $("#content > div").map(function () {
        return this.id || null;
    }).get().join("_");

    window[varname] = "Hello World";

    console.log("varname = "+varname);
    console.log("value = "+window[varname])
});
```

take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cgt5D/)

Hope this helps

Thanks,
Dhiraj